# keyboard macro with input-method inserts characters twice

Tags: keyboard-macros, input-method

When I define keyboard macro with some input method enabled (lets say, `english-dvorak`), `self-insert` commands are repeated twice.

For example, if I define macro like this:
<kbd>F3</kbd>`insert chars asdf`<kbd>F4</kbd>
and then hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, I will get the following line:

```
insert chars asdf
```

But if I'll use some input method:
<kbd>F3</kbd>`insert chars`<kbd>C-\</kbd>`asdf`<kbd>F4</kbd>
, I will get:

```
insert chars aaooeeuu
```

Characters that were typed with `english-dvorak` input method enabled are repeated twice when macro is called. This happens with all input methods.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps there's a bug here. Consider reporting it (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), if you don't get a helpful answer here. The Emacs developers will let you know if it is, in fact, a bug.

Comment: Turns out that it is a bug and it's fixed in Emacs 27. https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=40988

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. Please consider adding that as an answer here, to help others. (You can accept your own answer.)